# create ODataModelBuilder in web.api that has HasNavigationPropertyLink for FK int

Tags: foreign-keys, odata, asp.net-web-api

I have to class for example:
I want to create NavigationPropertyLink between Class B to class A when AId is a FK.
I succeed to do it for collections but failed to do it for int. I want the ability to Go to

class A through B.

```
 Class A
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int Name { get; set; }
}

Class B
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int AId { get; set; }//This is a FK to class A
  public int Name { get; set; }
}

ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataModelBuilder();
EntitySetConfiguration<A> aEntity = builder.EntitySet<A>("A");
EntitySetConfiguration<B> bEntity = builder.EntitySet<B>("B");
```

Answer (score 0):

Class B should have a direct reference to Class A through a property. web API OData doesn't understand foreign keys.

```
Class A
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int Name { get; set; }
}

Class B
{
  public int Id { get; set; }      
  public int Name { get; set; }
  public A A { get; set; } // navigation property.
}
```